# Reluctant quantifier acting greedy

Tags: java, regex, reluctant-quantifiers

I have this code:

```
String result = text;

    String regex = "((\\(|\\[)(.+)(\\)|\\])){1}?";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(result);

    System.out.println("start");
    System.out.println(result);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
        System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end() + " ");
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
    System.out.println("finish");
```

And I have a string that I want to match:

```
Some text sentence or sentences [something 234] (some things)
```

And the output I get when executing:

```
start
some text sentence or sentences [something 234] (some things)
Start index: 32 End index: 61 [something 234] (some things)
finish
```

Now I actually want it to find the found cases in brackets separately, so to find:
[something 234] in one match
(some things) as the second match

Can anyone please help me build the regex accordingly? I am not sure how to put the reluctant quantifier for the whole regular expression, so I surrounded the whole bracketed elements in another brackets. But I don't understand why this reluctant quantifier is acting greedy here and what do I need to do to change that?

Comment: do you want the content inside `[]` and `()`?

Comment: `.+` is not greedy. `.+?` would be.

Comment: Also `{1}?` seems redundant.

Comment: also, alternation can be avoided

Comment: @rock321987 yes, I need the content inside of each of these brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{1}` in regex is redundant since any element without specified quantifier needs to be found once. Also making it *reluctant* doesn't make sense since it doesn't describe *range* of possible repetitions (like `{min,max}` where adding `?` would tell regex engine to make number of repetitions in that range as close to `min` as possible). Here `{n}` describes precise number of repetition so `min` = `max` = `n`.

Now you should be able to solve your problem by making `.+` (content between brackets) reluctant. To do so use `.+?`.

So try with:

```
String regex = "((\\(|\\[)(.+?)(\\)|\\]))";
```

Comment: Hmm, seems to work, but I still don't get how making the quantifier reluctant for the content between brackets makes ir work? Why put it there as I'm searching a match for the brackets and the content, not just the content? I'm totally confused, I would have never come up with the idea to put the reluctant modifier on the content...

Comment: Try to think how should single result look like. It should be `(...)` and `[...]`. So if you have string like `aaa (foo) [bar] baz` regex should be able to find (mandatory) `(` and `)` and as small range of characters between them. That is why we are making that `.+` which represents characters between either `(` `[` and `]` `)` reluctant (minimal). Maybe this tutorial will explain it better: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy